# Limit the value of angle theta in ezpolar plot

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the function as shown in figure below:

[image]

`where the red curve denote for V = 200*1.6*1e-22` and `the blue curve denotes for V = 285*1.6*1e-22`

```
clear all
close all
clc
syms phi
l = 50*1e-9;
D   = 200*1e-9;
E  = 80*1.6*1e-22;
v  = 1e+6;
h  = 6.626*1e-34/(2*pi);
V  = 200*1.6*1e-22;
ky = (2*pi/l).*sin(phi);

q_x = sqrt((E - V).^2./((h*v).^2 - ky.^2));

% vpa(q_x,5)
T = cos(phi).^2./(1 - cos(q_x.*D).^2.*sin(phi).^2);

ezpolar(T)
```

It works great but I want to show the plot only between the `-90 < phi < 90`, I tried `ezpolar(T,[-pi/2 pi/2])` it gives the plot in region -90 to 90 but the empty region does also appear. How to remove that left half semicircular area where the plot is not there.

Comment: please stop using the mathematica tag. mathematica is a completely different program unrelated to matlab.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to evaluate the function in the `(x,y)` interval `x=(-1,1)` and `y(-1,1)` you can define a grid of `X` and `Y` values using the functin `meshgrid`

**Edit**

Updated the call to `surf` (ref. to the comment from Hunter Jiang)

```
a=0.000000000142
X=[-1:.1:1];
Y=X;
[x,y]=meshgrid(X,Y);
z=2*cos(sqrt(3).*y.*a) + 4*cos((sqrt(3).*y.*a)/2).*cos((3.*x.*a)/2) - 1;
%surf(z)
surf(x,y,z)
```

Then you can use the function `surf` to plot the results.

Comment: `surf(x,y,z)` may better :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the code in the answer.